# Aurelia-Cli npm update to latest version creates file system error

Tags: npm-install, aurelia

I updated to the latest version of Aurelia-cli yesterday, but it looks like something is messed up with my machine. 
I'm running on Windows 10.

When running au I get the following errors.

File system : Unexpected error--

[image]

I have done uninstall and cleared npm cache and reinstalled Aurelia-Cli, but same error.

Comment: You're using an old version of NodeJS. Download the updated version from the official website.

Comment: That was it, thank you!

Comment: Please, accept my answer or delete this question if you want. In this way we don't keep this as an "unsolved problem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old version of NodeJS. Download the updated version from the official website.